# Looking for a way to implement multiple proxies into a httpclient get/send request system

Tags: c#, proxy, httprequest, httpclient, credentials

So far I'm using a IWebProxy based custom class I saw another user use to accomplish the multiple proxies per httpclient, but I've tried a few different methods and I

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

namespace Amaz_ing
{
        public class WebProxyService : IWebProxy
        {
            private IWebProxy proxy;

            public IWebProxy Proxy
            {
                get => proxy ?? (proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy);
            set { proxy = value; }
            }

        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get => Proxy.Credentials;
            set => Proxy.Credentials = value;
        }


        public WebProxyService()
            {
            }

            public WebProxyService(IWebProxy proxy)
            {
                Proxy = proxy;
            }

            public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
                => Proxy.GetProxy(destination);

            public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
                => Proxy.IsBypassed(host);
        }
    }
```

I've tried setting the credentials in the webproxy and then pushing the IWebProxy in the above class to that proxy, which works for the proxy change but not the credentials.

```
ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                    IWebProxy webproxy = new WebProxy(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxyaddy, proxyport)));
                    if (proxyname != "" && proxypass != "")
                    {
                        credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyname, proxypass);
                        webproxy.Credentials = credentials;
                    }
```

I've also tried setting the proxy via something like

`proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(user,pass);`

The only thing I can think of is trying to force the ICredentials to renew each time a proxy value is changed, but I don't know how I would accomplish this.

Comment: Can you post code that uses `WebProxyService`?

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Are you running from inside VS?  You may not have Admin when running inside VS.  Start VS by right click VS shortcut and then select Run As Admin.